# Make generator recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

There is nested structure for filters.

```
{
    where: [{
        relation: 'user',
        query: {
            where: [{
                relation: 'companies',
                query: {
                    ...
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to make recursive function to generate that type of query which returns anonymous function which takes argument to pass to final query.

For example for filter query like 'user.companies' it should returns:

```
function (fieldQuery) {
    return {
        where: [{
            relation: 'user',
            query: {
                where: [{
                    relation: 'companies',
                    query: fieldQuery
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

What is the better way to make that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to make that function

```
let queryString = 'user.companies'
let depthArray = queryString.split('.')

function createDepth (depthArray) {

    return fieldQuery => ({
        where: [
            {
                relation: depthArray[0],
                query: depthArray.length <= 1
                    ? fieldQuery
                    : createDepth(depthArray.slice(1))(fieldQuery)
            }
        ]
    })
}
```

Comment: i like yours better

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
// Usage:
fq = 'Some FieldQuery';
filter = 'users.companies.jobs';
result = fieldQuery(fq, filter);

// Recursive function.
// Call with 2 arguments, leave the 3rd one undefined.
function fieldQuery(fq, filter, result=undefined) {
  // Index of the last period in filter.
  var lastIndex = filter.lastIndexOf('.');
  // Starting index of the last relation in filter.
  var startsAt = lastIndex + 1

  // If the filter is empty (or illegal) we just return the most recent result.
  if (lastIndex <= 0 && startsAt >= filter.length) {
    return result;
  }

  // This would be the last relation.
  var relation = filter.substr(startsAt);
  // The rest of the filter, without the last relation.
  var restOfFilter = filter.substr(0, lastIndex);

  // Recursive function
  return fieldQuery(fq, restOfFilter, {
    'where': [{
      'relation': relation,
      // If result has not been defined before, query is fq.
      // Else, query is the previous result.
      'query': (typeof(result) === 'undefined') ? fq : result
    }]
  });
}
```

Comment: Yea, that can be another implementation.